# post unique value using jquery replaceWith out of php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, while-loop

I am trying to post a stock number to an external php file and return the image using ajax replaceWith but it only returns the same image everytime..

Here is my Index.php -

```
<?php include('inv_data.php');?>

<div id="invCont">
    <div id="invTitle">Inventory</div>
    <div id="invData"><?php echo $invData;?></div>
</div>

<div id="detailData"></div>

<script>
$("form").submit(function(e) {
var url = "invDetail.php"; 
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: $("form").serialize(), 
   success: function(data)
   {
         $("#detailData").replaceWith(data);
   }
 });
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Here is the inv_data.php with the form -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $stock = $row['stock'];

        $invData .= '<form id="invForm" method="post">';
        $invData .= '<input type="hidden" value="'.$stock.'" name="stock">';
        $invData .= '<input type="submit" value="'.$stock.'" name="getDetail" id="iStock">';
        $invData .= '</form>';

    }
}
```

And finally my invDetail.php -

```
$stock = $_POST['stock'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE stock = $stock";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $image = $row['imagelist'];
    }
}
echo '<div id="detailData"><img src="'.$image.'" id="image"/></div>';
```

It all works fine except when it post the data from the ajax call it gives me the same value everytime no matter which stock number is clicked, how do I do it where it gives the the image of the stock number clicked?

Comment: Try adding apostrophes in your SQL statement inside invDetail - `SELECT * FROM table WHERE stock = '{$stock}'`. What may be happening is that it is ignoring your where condition, resulting in you looping through the whole table and returning the last image.

Comment: Thanks ya I tried all which ways seeing if that was my issue but no luck..It is pulling the last stock number in the DB though

Comment: A couple of other things I noticed; The include to inv_data does not have the .php extension; What is happening to $inv_data variable inside inv_data.php?

Comment: Ya sorry I fixed that, I wrote most of this as an example as I didnt want to post all my script

Comment: OK I only ask because it's hard to get an idea as to what is happening without the full picture.

Comment: Ya sorry, I updated the question with the output of the inv_data.php variable.

Comment: The issue may be caused by `data: $("form").serialize(),` -- Every time you submit a form, it is grabbing the data from *every* form on the page, not just the current one. Change to `data: $(this).serialize(),`

Comment: Unrelated, but since you create `form`s inside a loop, you now have `n` number of repeating `id`s -> `id="invForm"`/`id="iStock"`. This can cause javascript issues as `id`s are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Ahh yes don't know why I didn't think to use classes, ill give it a go! Thank you

Comment: when I made that change it gives me a broken img tag @mulquin

Comment: OK we need to do some debugging. Using the browser Inspector, can you check the values of the forms and the resulting images?

Comment: Yep they are all correct, correct image and stock number to coorelating form

Comment: Gotta love programming as it just started working for some reason.. maybe it was a cache issue.. I will keep testing and report back but if you post your data:(this) answer I will accept it @mulquin as it works with that change

Comment: Great to heart! I have included an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be caused by `data: $("form").serialize()`.

Every time the form is submitted, it is grabbing the data from every form on the page, not just the current one.

Change to `data: $(this).serialize()`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help you rock!